# Can tuple-elements be in the same set as non-tuple-elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am wondering whether this is a valid set:
$\{1, (1,2), 3 \}$

I have never seen a set before that contains tuple- as well as non-tuple-elements.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that as a set.  There's also nothing wrong with $\{1, 2, \mathbb{R}, \{\varnothing\}, \nabla, x, y, \alpha\}$.

Comment: A set can contain any objects as elements of itself, regardless what those objects happen to be... be they tuples, functions, numbers, other sets, colors, or whatever else you might choose to imagine.  The only requirements is that they be well-defined whatever they are and depending on the set theory you ascribe to [The Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) and [The Axiom of Pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing) might put additional requirements such as you can't have the parent set be an element of itself.

Comment: It is worth emphasizing, $\{1,(1,2),3\}$ is a three element set.  Those three elements would be $1$ as one element, $(1,2)$ as another element, and $3$ as a third element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sets can contain arbitrary elements as long as they're distinguishable.